# Shift register uses too many logic elements

Tags: vhdl, shift-register

I have implemented a shift register in VHDL. It uses "BITS" as a parameter to be able to shift a user defined number to the right. It works as intended, but takes up 164 logic elements according to the Compilation Report in Quartus II. Can anyone tell me why my code is so terrible and maybe give me a hint or two to optimize it? :) Thank you in advance.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ssi_data_align is

    port
    (
        DATA_IN      : in   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        BITS         : in   std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        DATA_OUT     : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));

end entity;

architecture Behavioral of ssi_data_align is

begin

DATA_OUT <= std_logic_vector(SHIFT_RIGHT(unsigned(not DATA_IN), natural(32-(to_integer(unsigned(BITS))))));

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Five type casts and conversions in one line of code is a hint that you are using the wrong datatypes, for a start.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Reducing the type casts doesn't reduce the amount of logical elements in this case - I have already tried :(

Comment: It doesn't change the logic, true. But it usually makes for better code, simpler, easier to maintain and understand, and less verbose.

Comment: This is really a barrel shifter rather than a simple shift register.  Much of the logic usage is going to be from the mux structure required for a variable shift.

Comment: WRT conversions, if the VHDL-2008 package numeric_std_unsigned (warning, this is not necessarily supported in your synthesis tool) were referenced, then all of the unsigned and std_logic_vector conversions would not be needed.

Comment: Also on conversions, the conversion to natural should not be necessary, it is a subtype of integer and subtypes should convert automatically - did I miss something?

Comment: It would also simplify things to just use `unsigned`/`signed` instead of `std_[u]logic_vector` for ports/signals when dealing with numeric arrays. It cuts down on the conversions while maintaining isolation of the arithmetic signals. It more clearly expresses your intent versus augmenting `std_logic_vector` with arithmetic behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of time, try always shifting your data_in 32 times.  Then simply use the BITS as a selector to tap off on the appropriate clock cycle.  You should try using clocked logic to solve the problem as it will synthesize smaller.

Maybe something like this?

```
process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then

    SHIFT_DATA <= '0' & DATA_IN(30 downto 0);

    if BITS = count then
      DATA_OUT <= SHIFT_DATA;
      count <= 0;
    else
      count <= count + 1;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: I have used a modified version of your code. It worked like a charm and I save quite a lot of logic elements, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your design is not so bad. If you have a look at the typical cost of a Barrel shifter, then you are well in a defined area ([Wikipedia here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter#Cost) has a list of typical costs for a Barrel shifter.

How you could improve depends on your application.

- If you have enough time, you can shift over multiple clock cycles. This reduces the logic to a fixed-size 1 bit shifter and a small overhead for counting the number of shifts, which needs less logic elements (shifting by by a constant is quite cheap).
- If the shift size is static, you can replace it with a generic.

Comment: I have plenty of time in this application. I thought that this shift register would be a fixed size, but with a variable number of shifts, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: It is a fixed size. What you have is effectively 32 32-to-1 muxes (with some reduction from shifted in 0's). Matthias' suggestion is to perform a single bit shift over a variable number of clock cycles controlled by a counter.

Answer (score 0):

With a test bench for your design specification:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity data_align_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of data_align_tb is

    function image(inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end;

    signal DATA_IN:     std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal BITS:        std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
    signal DATA_OUT:    std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
begin

DUT:
    entity work.ssi_data_align 
        port map (
            DATA_IN => DATA_IN,
            BITS => BITS,
            DATA_OUT => DATA_OUT
        );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        for i in 0 to 31 loop
            BITS <= std_logic_vector(
                        TO_UNSIGNED(natural(i),5)
                    );
            wait for 1 ns;           
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;

MONITOR:
    process (DATA_OUT)
    begin
        report "BITS = " & image(BITS) & "    DATA_OUT = " & image(DATA_OUT);
    end process;

end architecture;
```

And a constant DATA_IN value of all '0's we see:

`../../../src/ieee/numeric_std-body.v93:2098:7:@0ms:(assertion warning): NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@0ms:(report note): BITS = uuuuu    DATA_OUT = uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@0ms:(report note): BITS = 00000    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000000000
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@1ns:(report note): BITS = 00001    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000000001
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@2ns:(report note): BITS = 00010    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000000011
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@3ns:(report note): BITS = 00011    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000000111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@4ns:(report note): BITS = 00100    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000001111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@5ns:(report note): BITS = 00101    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000011111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@6ns:(report note): BITS = 00110    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@7ns:(report note): BITS = 00111    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000001111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@8ns:(report note): BITS = 01000    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000011111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@9ns:(report note): BITS = 01001    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@10ns:(report note): BITS = 01010    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000001111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@11ns:(report note): BITS = 01011    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000011111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@12ns:(report note): BITS = 01100    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@13ns:(report note): BITS = 01101    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000001111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@14ns:(report note): BITS = 01110    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000011111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@15ns:(report note): BITS = 01111    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@16ns:(report note): BITS = 10000    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000001111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@17ns:(report note): BITS = 10001    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000011111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@18ns:(report note): BITS = 10010    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@19ns:(report note): BITS = 10011    DATA_OUT = 00000000000001111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@20ns:(report note): BITS = 10100    DATA_OUT = 00000000000011111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@21ns:(report note): BITS = 10101    DATA_OUT = 00000000000111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@22ns:(report note): BITS = 10110    DATA_OUT = 00000000001111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@23ns:(report note): BITS = 10111    DATA_OUT = 00000000011111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@24ns:(report note): BITS = 11000    DATA_OUT = 00000000111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@25ns:(report note): BITS = 11001    DATA_OUT = 00000001111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@26ns:(report note): BITS = 11010    DATA_OUT = 00000011111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@27ns:(report note): BITS = 11011    DATA_OUT = 00000111111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@28ns:(report note): BITS = 11100    DATA_OUT = 00001111111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@29ns:(report note): BITS = 11101    DATA_OUT = 00011111111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@30ns:(report note): BITS = 11110    DATA_OUT = 00111111111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:79:9:@31ns:(report note): BITS = 11111    DATA_OUT = 01111111111111111111111111111111`

Which shows from the last reported value that `DATA_IN(0)` isn't used and would likely result in one or more synthesis warnings.  You can also see from the first report statement after the meta values clear out that none of `DATA_IN` is used for a shift of 32 - BITS for `BITS` = "0000".

Your expression `natural(32-(to_integer(unsigned(BITS))))` produces values of 32 downto 1 for BITS `natural` equivalents of 0 to 31. You could code your shifter directly saving 7 logic elements while avoiding a plethora of religious objections over using type conversions for their intended purposes when eliminating the subtraction.

A one direction shifter with a range of 1 to 32 (or 0 to 31) is 5 levels of 2:1 multiplexers where each BITS 'bit' selects between one of two values to feed to the next level.  SHIFT_RIGHT provides an arithmetic shift (0 fills).

Expressing these multiplexers directly as single bit 2:1 multiplexers in a look up table (occupying a logic element) tells us you need 159 logic elements.  (31 + 32 + 32 + 32 + 32 for the 5 levels of multiplexers, the `not` is hidden in the first level).

There's a two's compliment relationship between BITS and 32 - BITS, and eliminating the the subtraction is done by commutation:

```
architecture foo of ssi_data_align is

begin 

SHIFTER:
    DATA_OUT <= std_logic_vector(
                    SHIFT_RIGHT(
                        unsigned('0' & not DATA_IN(31 downto 1)),
                        to_integer(unsigned(not BITS))
                    )
                );

end architecture;
```

The inversion of BITS and the pre-shift of DATA_IN.

As noted by Jim Lewis the type conversion to `natural` wasn't needed and in deference to Brian indentation and new line characters are added to enhance ease of maintenance and understanding.

It gives the same answer:

`../../../src/ieee/numeric_std-body.v93:2098:7:@0ms:(assertion warning): NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@1ns:(report note): BITS = 00000    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000000000
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@2ns:(report note): BITS = 00001    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000000001
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@3ns:(report note): BITS = 00010    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000000011
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@4ns:(report note): BITS = 00011    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000000111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@5ns:(report note): BITS = 00100    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000001111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@6ns:(report note): BITS = 00101    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000011111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@7ns:(report note): BITS = 00110    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000000111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@8ns:(report note): BITS = 00111    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000001111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@9ns:(report note): BITS = 01000    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000011111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@10ns:(report note): BITS = 01001    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000000111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@11ns:(report note): BITS = 01010    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000001111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@12ns:(report note): BITS = 01011    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000011111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@13ns:(report note): BITS = 01100    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000000111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@14ns:(report note): BITS = 01101    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000001111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@15ns:(report note): BITS = 01110    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000011111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@16ns:(report note): BITS = 01111    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000000111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@17ns:(report note): BITS = 10000    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000001111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@18ns:(report note): BITS = 10001    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000011111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@19ns:(report note): BITS = 10010    DATA_OUT = 00000000000000111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@20ns:(report note): BITS = 10011    DATA_OUT = 00000000000001111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@21ns:(report note): BITS = 10100    DATA_OUT = 00000000000011111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@22ns:(report note): BITS = 10101    DATA_OUT = 00000000000111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@23ns:(report note): BITS = 10110    DATA_OUT = 00000000001111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@24ns:(report note): BITS = 10111    DATA_OUT = 00000000011111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@25ns:(report note): BITS = 11000    DATA_OUT = 00000000111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@26ns:(report note): BITS = 11001    DATA_OUT = 00000001111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@27ns:(report note): BITS = 11010    DATA_OUT = 00000011111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@28ns:(report note): BITS = 11011    DATA_OUT = 00000111111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@29ns:(report note): BITS = 11100    DATA_OUT = 00001111111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@30ns:(report note): BITS = 11101    DATA_OUT = 00011111111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@31ns:(report note): BITS = 11110    DATA_OUT = 00111111111111111111111111111111
ssi_data_align.vhdl:84:13:@32ns:(report note): BITS = 11111    DATA_OUT = 01111111111111111111111111111111`

Still leaving `DATA_IN(0)` unused, but saving that subtract operation producing a 6 bit distance.

The pre-shift of DATA_IN costs no logic elements.